# Barchart in matplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have a range of values in a column named GRADES

```
Grades          count       
A               38616
B               658
G               16041
P               7590
C               33
```

I want to visualize column GRADE in my_data dataset in matplot .Am getting a blank a blank subplot with the below code:

```
fig, ax=plt.subplots()
ax.set(xlabel="Grade", ylabel="Count", title="Grade Distribution")
ax.bar('GRADE', align='center', data=my_data)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Well, it's because you haven't plotted anything?

Comment: the call signature of `ax.bar` is `ax.bar(x,y, *args,**kwargs)`, with x and y being the position and height of the bar. Is the my_data dataset a pandas dataframe?

Comment: That looks like you want to use seaborn syntax. Have a look on both documentations, seaborn and matplotlib and decide which one you want to use.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest yes it is

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing the call signatures of the plotting functions.

Assuming your data is in a pandas dataframe.

#### Using pandas plot function

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({"Grades" : list("ABGPC"),
                   "count" : [38616,658,16041,7590,33]})

df.plot(x ="Grades", y="count", kind="bar")

plt.show()
```

#### Using matplotlib bar plot

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({"Grades" : list("ABGPC"),
                   "count" : [38616,658,16041,7590,33]})

fig, ax=plt.subplots()
ax.set(xlabel="Grade", ylabel="Count")
ax.bar(df["Grades"], df["count"])

plt.show()
```

#### Using Seaborn `barplot`

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({"Grades" : list("ABGPC"),
                   "count" : [38616,658,16041,7590,33]})

ax = sns.barplot(x="Grades", y="count", data=df)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to use the bar function is given [here](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar.html?highlight=bar#matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar). You are supposed to pass the data as `x` and `y` and the grades must be passed as `tick_lable`

```
grades = ['A', 'B', 'C']
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [5, 7, 3]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set(xlabel="Grade", ylabel="Count", title="Grade Distribution")
ax.bar(x, y, align='center', tick_label=grades)
plt.show()
```

**Output**
[image]

Comment: where are you getting the values in the list of x,y

Comment: @BillehSarkozy I have initialized the x and y arrays in the beginning. X is just a list of natural numbers `1,2,3,4,5...`. In your case I dont know what my_data contain, so you will have to extract the x, and labels from that.

Comment: my_data is a dataframe that has multiple columns like age,nationality,grades, etc

Comment: You will have t convert that dataframe into 3 separate lists of equal length. `x_list`, `y_list` and `label_list`